# Fastify setCookie not setting cookies

Tags: next.js, fastify

I have a back-end using **fastify** and a **nextjs** front end, im trying to set a cookie on my browser using this code but is not working.

```js
if (!sessionId) {
      sessionId = randomUUID();

      reply.setCookie("sessionId", sessionId, {
        path: "/",
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
        signed: true,
        httpOnly: true,
      });
}
```

https://github.com/MatthewAraujo/polls/blob/main/backend/src/http/routes/vote-on-poll.ts
this is the github repo where im using the `setCookie`

https://github.com/MatthewAraujo/polls/blob/votes/frontend/src/components/Poll.tsx
this is the github repo where im fetching de route for `setCookie`

I tried to get my cookies in the browser and this is not happening

Comment: The cookie is ignore because of the httponly flag. Turn it off